# Chart.js -> line chart -> multiple points with the same X

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) to create some charts, and I need to make line chart that have multiple entries for the same point in the X axes.

In other words, this:
[image]

Whatever I try, i can not create it to look like the image.
Dose anyone know how I can manage this (with plugins or without)?

Comment: so whats your type of data , what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a **scatter** graph, the data has to be an array of objects with x and y, also you can adjust the tension of the line.

```
var data = {
  datasets: [{
    label: "Dataset #1",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    borderWidth: 2,
    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
    hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    data: [{
       x: 0,
       y: 5
     }, 
     {
       x: 1,
       y: 10
     },
     {
       x: 1,
       y: 5
     },
     {
       x: 3,
       y: 10
     }]
  }]
};

var option = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
     stacked: true,
     gridLines: {
       display: true,
       color: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)"
     }
    }],
    xAxes: [{
     gridLines: {
       display: true,
       color: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)"
     }
   }]
 },
 elements: {
    line: {
        tension: .1, // bezier curves
    }
 }
};

 Chart.Scatter('chart_0', {
    options: option,
    data: data
 });
```

[Codepen]https://codepen.io/devil-geek/pen/KrQWBP